# read html file from JSF project root folder

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat

I dont know how to explain it but let me try :

I have a eclipse JSF project named web-gestao

I would like to call from URL : http://www.domainxxx/simplefile.html **and NOT** `http://www.domainxxx/web-gestao/simplefile.html`

I need this for google verification purposes.

Comment: you have to configure virtual hosting in tomcat , or rename your war ROOT.war and put it in wabapps of your tomcat.

Comment: you are referring to context root and/or virtual hosts of the application server

Comment: referring to context root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jboss-web>
    <!-- URL to access the web module -->

    <context-root>/</context-root>
```

...
...
...